# Replace no-phone symbols from phone in jquery with regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I got phone number in `div` with `id=phoneNumber` in format +7 (999) 999-9999
I need to replace symbols: '(',')',' ','-' in it.
I'm trying to do it like this:

```
phone=$('#phoneNumber').html();
phone=phone.replace('/[\s|\(|\)]/g','');
```

For some reason this doesn't replace anything. What's wrong? Are there better ways to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove quote from regex:

```
phone = phone.replace(/[\s()]/g, '');
```

Also there is no need to escape `(` and `)` inside character class nor is the need to use `pipe` for alternation.

Comment: Thanx, as site allows me, I'll approve your answer.